# Call list from def

Tags: python

I have this def:

```
def get_price_table():

        pricing_table = [3.60, 2.90, 2.20, 2.10, 1.70, 1.30]

        #converting the list objects into floats with two decimals
        pricing_table = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in pricing_table]

        return pricing_table
```

Now I want to call it in the following class:

```
class CalcPrice():

    def compute_price(self, info: UIInfo) -> float:
        # get number of tariefeenheden
        tariefeenheden: int = Tariefeenheden.get_tariefeenheden(info.from_station, info.to_station)

        PricingTable.get_price_table()

        if info.travel_class == UIClass.FirstClass:
            if info.discount == UIDiscount.TwentyDiscount:
                price = PricingTable.get_price_table.pricing_table[1]
            elif info.discount == UIDiscount.FortyDiscount:
                price = PricingTable.get_price_table.pricing_table[2]
            else:
                price = PricingTable.get_price_table.pricing_table[0]

        elif info.travel_class == UIClass.SecondClass:
            if info.discount == UIDiscount.TwentyDiscount:
                price = PricingTable.get_price_table.pricing_table[4]
            elif info.discount == UIDiscount.FortyDiscount:
                price = PricingTable.get_price_table.pricing_table[5]
            else:
                price = PricingTable.get_price_table.pricing_table[3]

        #Double price if returnticket is applicable
        if info.way == UIWay.Return:
            price *= 2

        price = price * 0.02 * tariefeenheden
        return round(price, 2)
```

But now I get an AttributeError saying 'function' object has no attribute 'pricing_table'. What is the proper way to get an element of the list from another def?

Comment: Post the traceback. We shouldn't have to guess which line has the error.

Comment: `PricingTable` isn't defined. Is it a module? A class? The function converts `pricing_table` from a list of floats to a list of strings... when you use it, which version do you want? I think it would be simpler if `pricing_table` was just assigned the strings from the beginning. You may loose some precision converting a decimal float to a binary float, so its best to avoid when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you meant to do this?

```
class CalcPrice():

    def compute_price(self, info: UIInfo) -> float:
        # get number of tariefeenheden
        tariefeenheden: int = Tariefeenheden.get_tariefeenheden(info.from_station, info.to_station)

        pricing_table = PricingTable.get_price_table()

        if info.travel_class == UIClass.FirstClass:
            if info.discount == UIDiscount.TwentyDiscount:
                price = pricing_table[1]
            elif info.discount == UIDiscount.FortyDiscount:
                price = pricing_table[2]
            else:
                price = pricing_table[0]

        elif info.travel_class == UIClass.SecondClass:
            if info.discount == UIDiscount.TwentyDiscount:
                price = pricing_table[4]
            elif info.discount == UIDiscount.FortyDiscount:
                price = pricing_table[5]
            else:
                price = pricing_table[3]

        #Double price if returnticket is applicable
        if info.way == UIWay.Return:
            price *= 2

        price = price * 0.02 * tariefeenheden
        return round(price, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_price_table` is a method defined out of the scope. So you just need to import the proper module (if that function is not in the same module) and call it directly: `pricing_table = get_price_table()`

My two cents:
As it is now, `get_price_table` function does the same always, so a better approach is to define it as a map, or a "constant" value:

```
PRICING_TABLE = [
  ...
]
```